# SVG not clickable and inline SVG with datauri not shown

Tags: html, svg, xlink

I have a SVG file named `cherry.svg` defined like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    x="0px" y="0px" width="800px" height="1280px" viewBox="0 0 800 1280" enable-background="new 0 0 800 1280" xml:space="preserve">
    <image id="image0" width="800" height="1280" x="0" y="0"


    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAUACAIAAAAwbqEzAAABHGlDQ1BpY2MAACiRY2BgMnB0cXJl
EmBgyM0rKQpyd1KIiIxSYD/PwMbAzAAGicnFBY4BAT4gdl5+XioDBvh2jYERRF/WBZmFKY8XcCUX
FJUA6T9AbJSSWpzMwMBoAGRnl5cUAMUZ5wDZIknZYPYGELsoJMgZyD4CZPOlQ9hXQOwkCPsJiF0E
9ASQ/QWkPh3MZuIAmwNhy4DYJakVIHsZnPMLKosy0zNKFAwtLS0VHFPyk1IVgiuLS1JzixU885Lz
iwryixJLUlOAaiHuAwNBiEJQiGkANVpokuhvggAUDxDW50Bw+DKKnUGIIUByaVEZlMnIZEyYjzBj
jgQDg/9SBgaWPwgxk14GhgU6DAz8UxFiaoYMDAL6DAz75gAAwMZP/aCJEEUAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYA....... (lines of rubbish)

    <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
        <rect x="535" y="28" fill="#fff" opacity="0.8" width="150" height="750" />
    </a>
</svg>
```

And a simple page to show it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Index</title>
        <style>
            /* Make the image responsive */
            img {
              height: 100%;
              width: auto;
              z-index: 2000;
            }

            .center {
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width: 50%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <img src="img/cherry.svg" class="center">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As I open in the browser, it is not clickable, but if I right click on the image and "Open image in another tab", it works.

Chrome/IE reports the same.

---

I read somewhere that "only inline SVG can be clicked". OK, but if I include the `<svg></svg>` image in the main page, it is not recognised and browsers reports error and image not shown.

Now what?

Comment: _“Now what?”_ - now you owe us a proper example of how you tried to embed this directly in HTML, so that we can check if you did that correctly, or perhaps messed it up (for example by, say, naively copying XML declaration and doctype of the SVG into the HTML as well.)

Comment: anything in an <img> tag is not interactive. You'd need to use a <object> or <iframe> or inline SVG.

Comment: Thanks for all. I have figured out why. See explained below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. @CBroe I will explain here what I did. And I don't want to use `<object>` or `<iframe>`, I think that is overkill.

I embedded the SVG in my page like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Purple index</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            /* Make the image responsive */
            img {
              height: 100%;
              width: auto;
              z-index: 2000;
            }

            .center {
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width: 50%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="page-wrapper">

                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="center">
                        <!-- <img src="img/cherry.svg" class="center"> -->
                        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            x="0px" y="0px" width="800px" height="1280px" viewBox="0 0 800 1280" enable-background="new 0 0 800 1280" xml:space="preserve">
                            <image id="image0" width="800" height="1280" x="0" y="0" 

                            xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAUACAIAAAAwbqEzAAABHGlDQ1BpY2MAACiRY2BgMnB0cXJl
                                EmBgyM0rKQpyd1KIiIxSYD/PwMbAzAAGicnFBY4BAT4gdl5+XioDBvh2jYERRF/WBZmFKY8XcCUX
                                FJUA6T9AbJSSWpzMwMBoAGRnl5cUAMUZ5wDZIknZYPYGELsoJMgZyD4CZPOlQ9hXQOwkCPsJiF0E
                                9ASQ/QWkPh3MZuIAmwNhy4DYJakVIHsZnPMLKosy0zNKFAwtLS0VHFPyk1IVgiuLS1JzixU885Lz.... />
                            <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
                                <rect x="59" y="491" fill="#fff" opacity="0" width="452" height="89" />
                            </a>
                            <a xlink:href="http://www.youtube.com">
                                <rect x="59" y="601" fill="#fff" opacity="0" width="452" height="89" />
                            </a>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the browser seems to fail at line break in the `datauri` part. I think it just recognise the data in one line.

I joined all lines and all is fine now. Tricky.

PS: I converted the JPG(a rather complicated one) into SVG with this site: https://www.aconvert.com/image/jpg-to-svg/. The output is of high quality, but the `datauri` comes with line breaks. Just to remind all that you must look into the file content to avoid my situation.